# Android - TranslateAnimate one view to another view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to include a simple animation in my app where a <strike>view</strike> widget moves to another <strike>view</strike> widget.

The code I have written is:

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(view1.getTranslationX(), view1.getTranslationY(), view2.getTranslationX(), view2.getTranlationY());
animate.setDuration(500);
view1.startAnimation(animate);
```

The problem is that `view1` is a custom view inherited from `ViewSwitcher` whereas `view2` is a `Button`. getTranslation() gives no such method exception for both.

How can I get the view's position on screen and is this the right way to do the animation ?

**Note:** The `ViewSwitcher` is part of a `ListView` item so it also needs to cross over its `ListView` boundary to get to the `Button`(just in case that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like `getTranslationX()` and `getTranslationY()` simply return an offset value that may be applied to the actual view position, and not the position itself.  You will want to use methods like `getLeft()` and `getTop()` to get the x/y position value of a view relative to its parent (in this case, the `ListView`).

If you need more global coordinates, use `getLocationInWindow()` or `getLocationOnScreen()` to get the view's position relative to the global display hierarchy.  These methods do not return the position, but rather fill it into the `int[]` you provide as a parameter.

All of these methods can be called on any `View`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I can tell, it works but because `view1` is in a `ListView`, it just disappears. I reckon it moves to the desired location but because it does so behind the other views in the `ListView`, I can't see it. I tried bringToFront() but that doesn't help. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, there's not enough information in the code/context you have posted to make any determinations about the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try to explain. `view1` is an icon for a `ListView`. Something like the pictures that you would have in a contacts listview. `view2` is at a different location within the same screen/LinearLayout. Analogous to a title in the contacts app. When I animate the picture, it moves but it does not go beyond the boundary of the `ListView`. I tried `.setClipChildren(false)` on the 'ListView' but it completely distorts the whole view.

Comment: I accepted your answer cause this seems to be a totally different question. I looked around and it seems so far `FrameLayout` is the only way to do this. I wonder if that can be done programatically so I don't have to change the Layout XML.

Comment: on calling getLocationWindow() ,it returns height and width as 0.

Comment: @hk99 Seeing as how the API returns an x/y location only, your comment doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I'm not sure, if you did everything correct..

As for me, the easiest way to implement animation in Android is to use ViewFlipper. Maybe you should consider wrapping your views with it.

Here you have some post about using translation and alpha animations with ViewFlipper in case you follow my suggestion http://kevinrohling.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/using-a-slide-transition-with-viewflipper/

Comment: Great stuff... but its seems to be about transitioning between activity views. My question is regarding the movement of views (widgets) on the same screen (with one being in a ListView). Does this work for this scenario ?